# Is there a keyspace event in redis for a key entering the database that isn't already present?

Tags: redis

I have a program that utilizes a redis key with an expire time set. I want to detect when there is a new entry to the data set. I can tell when there is a removal by listening for the "expired" event, but the "set" and "expire" events are fired every time the key is set, even if it's already in the database.

Is there a keyspace event for a NEW key appearing?

Comment: don't think there is in the current official version, but maybe you can achieve that by a lua script

Answer (score 2):

There's no keyspace configuration that detects that a key was overwritten vs. newly added.

If you are primarily using the SET command, you may be able to take advantage of the `NX` option and publish a custom event based on the result.  Obviously this isn't an ideal approach, but it's something.
https://redis.io/commands/set

Example of a custom event:

```
PUBLISH __keyevent@0__:new_data_entry new_key
```

Details on that here: https://redis.io/topics/notifications#type-of-events

Hope that helps.